# Format date on 2 lines

Tags: swift, date

I want date to be on 2 lines

```
public func smdt(date:NSDate)->NSString{
    var dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "h:mma dd MMMM yyyy"
    return dateFormatter.stringFromDate(date)
}
```

I add time in string, but I want to start new line before "dd"

Example: `h:mma\ndd MMMM yyyy`

Should be:

> 7:12PM
>
> 19 May 2015

In `.dateFormat`, `\n` doesn't work... The only way to be done is to detect where is the first whitespace between PM and 19 and replace it with `\n`. How it can be done ?

It has to work on every timezone on the earth. That means I can't use AM/PM for separating...

Comment: It works for me if I put `\n` in the format string. Show us the output you get when you put `\n` in the format string.

Comment: I tryed `h:mma\ndd MMMM yyyy` to prevent spaces and doesn't work... I will try with spaces one moment :)

Comment: yes now it works.. what should I do with question. Self Answer or Delete ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your code should work. Maybe it confuses you, that if you check the values of your return-values from within the playground for example, the value is like that:

```
"6:21PM\n19 May 2015"
```

But if I use your code like that:

```
public func smdt(date:NSDate)->NSString{
    var dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "h:mma\ndd MMMM yyyy"
    return dateFormatter.stringFromDate(date)
}
```

And call the value by using `println`:

```
println(smdt2(NSDate()))
```

The value printed out is like that:

```
6:22PM
19 May 2015
```

So you can use your code like you tried already.

But you also could split the hour and day/month like that and concate it later:

```
public func smdt(date:NSDate)->NSString{
    var dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "h:mma"
    var hour = dateFormatter.stringFromDate(date)
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd MMMM yyyy"

    var otherPart = dateFormatter.stringFromDate(date)
    return "\(hour)\n\(otherPart)"
}
```