# How do I format date in objective C?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I basically have this code right now and I am trying to format by having a new line in between but it doesn't give me a new line. Am I doing it correctly?

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
NSLocale *twelveHourLocale = [[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_DB"];
dateFormatter.locale = twoHourLocale;
formatString = [NSDateFormatter dateFormatFromTemplate:@"EEEE \n hh:mm" options:0 locale:[NSLocale currentLocale]];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:formatString];
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Converting a date format in objective C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6724180/converting-a-date-format-in-objective-c)

Comment: @JLewkovich It's not a duplicate; this question concerns the behavior of ``-dateFormatFromTemplate:locale:options:`, whereas the suggested dupe is just a matter of a bad format string.

Answer (score 1):

> I basically have this code right now and I am trying to format by having a new line in between but it doesn't give me a new line. Am I doing it correctly?

The point of calling `-dateFormatFromTemplate:locale:options:` is to get back a format string that's properly formatted for the specified locale. That is, the method looks at the date components you specify and arranges them to suit the local custom, like "Jan 2 2019" in the US, but "2 Jan 2019" in Europe. I think it basically ignores any parts of the template that it doesn't recognize as a date component specifier. If it's moving the date components around, how would it know where to place the non-date parts that it doesn't know about?

**If you don't care about different locales** and just want a date that has a newline in it, then you can skip that method and just create the template string yourself:

```
formatString = @"EEEE \n hh:mm";
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:formatString];
NSString *dateString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];
NSLog(@"%@", dateString);
```

The code above will log the current date with a newline between the weekday and the time, so `-stringFromDate:` will happily use your format string and keep the newline.

**If you *do* care about locales** but still want the newline, you'll have to either create your own locale-specific date format strings, or call `-dateFormatFromTemplate:locale:options:` and then insert the newline at the right spot in the result.

Answer (score 0):

It seems it should work based on this question: [Format date on 2 lines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30330870/format-date-on-2-lines)

However, that's in swift, so there could be different implementation details. Worst case scenario, you can split your 'EEEE' and 'hh:mm' into 2 different formatters and concatenate them.